# Spring boot 1.5.6 - logging Garbage Collection activity

Tags: java, spring-boot, garbage-collection

How can i log the GC activity in file. Running and monitoring the application with jConsole/ JProfiler is not an option, because it is runtime monitoring, and i don't have history let's say for when GC is activated.

The problem that i have is with http hanging requests and my assumption is that these frozen/hanging requests are due GC activity.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot application is just a normal java application. Jvm allows for arguments on process startup, some of them related to configuring gc log output (including specific file you want these logs to be).

Exact options you have depend on jvm version you are working with, but most of them are pretty standard between versions: look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) (Debugging Options section).

You only need to add your needed params to the "java -jar ...." command you start your application with.